# Adjectival form of 'policy'?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, derivational-morphology

I am looking for an adjective that means "of or relating to policies".

Of course, *political* first comes to mind. It, however, is much more to do with *politics*, rather than *policy*.

**Examples:**

- "I disagree with the official's –––– decisions." We could insert *political* but this would focus the sentence on the *game of politics*—the networking, the ladder-climbing, etc. People often just use the noun policy, but is there an actual adjective?
- "I am  interested in the city's –––– future."

Comment: Just to clarify, in your second example, are you looking for an alternative to "I am interested in the city's *policy* future"?

Comment: @lithic Correct

Comment: Ran into this too. A friend suggests "quasi-governmental"

Answer (score 3):

In English, it is often acceptable to use a substantive (noun) as adjective. It could therefore be acceptable to write:

> I disagree with the official's policy decisions.

Though I would write:

> I disagree with the official's decisions about policy.

Similarly:

> I am interested in the city's future policy.

Unless there a particular reason to use an adjective?

Comment: I might be asking too much: Really looking for a parallel structure with *political*. "I am interested in how the city's physical and –––– form affect ..."

Comment: His answer still fits there. Although it may not sound like it, you can say *"I am interested in how the city's physical and policy form affect..."* ([Definition 1a](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/policy))

Comment: I really dislike the word substantive for the word noun.